# How to set the tab name to an alias hostname of the remote host I'm connected to?

Tags: ssh, terminal, hostname

As you might know, by default, the hostname of an AWS instance is something like `ip-12-34-56-78.us-west-2.compute.internal`, so when I ssh to this host, the tab name is changed to `root@ip-12-34-56-78` (a bit of difficult for me to identify which is which).

Since I have the following in the `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host mail.domain.com
    Hostname 1.2.3.4
    User root

Host web.domain.com
    Hostname 5.6.7.8
    User root
```

I'm wondering that is there any way to change the tab name to the "alias" hostname of the remote host I'm connected to (instead of the "real" hostname):

[image: iTerm tab title when ssh]

---

My current `PS1` settings:

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

I have tried to add a ssh wrapper into `~/.bashrc`:

```
ssh() {
    echo -ne "\033]0;${@: -1}\007"
    exec ssh $@
}
```

then `. ~/.bashrc` and test by running `ssh web.domain.com`:

- while **connecting**: the tab name is changed to `web.domain.com`, as expected
- when **connected**: it is overwritten with `root@ip-5-6-7-8`

Why? Is there something related to `PS1` here?

---

**UPDATE Fri Jun  6 21:58:04 ICT 2014**

There is something quite strange going on: looks like this only happened with AWS instance. With other hosts, the tab name remain after logging in.

`PS1` on the AWS instance:

```
# echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

`PS1` on the other hosts:

```
~ echo $PS1
\[\]\[\][\[\]\t\[\]] \u\[\]@\[\]\h\[\]\[\]:\[\]\w\[\] \[\]
```

I also have tried to set the `PS1` variable on the AWS to the value of working host but it didn't help.

Comment: have you tried setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: @Gnouc: set to what? How can I take the first argument when `ssh` and put it into `PROMPT_COMMAND`? My current setting: `export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$(basename "$(dirname "$PWD")")/${PWD##*/}\007"'`.

Comment: It's probably not quite what you want but it might be worth a look: Try `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname` from _inside the VM_ and see if this value is better suited for a tab name then what `hostname` gets you. ([More about metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html))

Comment: @sr_: I know that command, it does not help in this case. The thing is when I opened multiple tabs, I would like to quick switch to a specific tab by pressing <kbd>command</kbd> + tab number.

Comment: @quanta: maybe `export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}: ${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"'`. It seems that you want to change `HOSTNAME` to the alias name which define in `.ssh/config`?

Comment: @Gnouc: yes. But notice that I don't want the tab name is something like `quanta@MacBook-Pro...` when I'm on localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be because upon logging into the remote shell session, that server's PS1 is sending you back the same `\033]0;title\007` command sequence which makes your terminal program intercept and display accordingly. You really don't have any effect of editing your PS1 on local workstation.

I had a similar requirement and what I did is on the remote shell's bashrc, I put something like the following

```
PS1="\033]0;(tools)\007\015[\u@\h \W]# "
```

The tools is the designated name by which I wanted to identify the title. Effectively, the title shows it correctly in the terminal, and the command prompt is what I have normally.

Comment: +1. I know that I can do this or simply change the hostname on the remote host, but why it does not happen with other hosts (that has `PS1` is set to `\[\]\[\][\[\]\t\[\]] \u\[\]@\[\]\h\[\]\[\]:\[\]\w\[\] \[\]`? See my updated question.

Comment: echo $PS1 > ps1.out in your server and check what do you see in that file. Probably that PS1 does not have the ESC sequence embedded into it. You can't see it by just echo $PS1 in console. Did I get your question correct ?

Comment: It has the same value as I posted `\[\]\[\][\[\]\t\[\]] \u\[\]@\[\]\h\[\]\[\]:\[\]\w\[\] \[\]`.

One more question: with my above ssh wrapper, whenever I press ctrl-D or type `exit` it close my tab instead of close the session and return the local prompt(`quanta@MacBook-Pro`).

Comment: You should have something in your server's /etc/bashrc or so which does this trick. In my case for xterm like, it sets PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"' which seems to do this trick. The reason for your tab to exit is because you are exec'ing ssh and that image replaces your bash process. Now when you exit from the shell, ssh client dies along with that since there is no more bash process to hold you back on terminal, it completely exits.

Comment: There is a dilemma here: if I use ssh wrapper, it works as expect with some hosts but ctrl-D close the tab. If not, I have to set the PS1 on the remote hosts. Any better way?

Comment: Why don't use it just this way. Don't exec ssh. I tried it myself and works => ssh() {
    echo -ne "\033]0;${@: -1}\007"
    /usr/bin/ssh $@
}